# Map volume controls to Function Keys on Sierra

Tags: keyboard, display, audio, macos

Since [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) is not yet updated for macOS Sierra, is there a way to map volume controls (increase, decrease and mute) to function keys (in my case to F10, F11, F12)?

From System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Display, I can map brightness keys, but is there a workaround for volume too?

To be clear, it's not an Apple keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

[Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) is the successor of Karabiner and available for macOS Sierra.